# Electric and magnetic field direction for a plane wave

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

In the book introduction to electrodynamics by David J. Griffiths p.395, we have a plane wave with the fields

$$\vec{E}(z,t) = \vec{E_0}e^{i(kz-\omega t)}$$
$$\vec{B}(z,t) = \vec{B_0}e^{i(kz-\omega t)}$$

Faraday's law say $\nabla \times \vec{E} = - \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$

Griffiths doesn't tell if the electric field has a $x$ or $y$ component, but I assume $E_0$ in $x$ direction.

Using the Faraday's law, Griffiths found

$$-k \vec{(E_0)_y} = \omega(\vec{B_0})_x$$

Using the curl for the left hand side I found $\frac{\partial E_0}{dz} - \frac{\partial 0}{\partial x} =  k \vec{(E_0)_y}$

I don't see where the minus sign come from.

Comment: Yes that's the curl of E (although you forgot the i), now take the tiime derivative of B and you'll see the minus sign.

Comment: Since the time derivative of B gives me -$\omega(\vec{B_0})_x$, I have $- (-\omega(\vec{B_0})_x)$ which is positive.